# Commit the transaction after exception is raised

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I tried looking up for the solution but failed to find one. I understand  that postgres rollbacks all the transactions once an exception is raised. But my requirement is to log a certain exception into a database table.

Following is a sample code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test(
in_var numeric DEFAULT NULL::numeric)
RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF in_var=0
THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION using errcode='INELG';
ELSE IF in_var=1
THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION using errcode='INVAL';
ELSE
    RETURN in_var;
END IF;
begin
EXCEPTION
WHEN sqlstate 'INELG' 
THEN
    INSERT INTO LOG_TBL(in_par,error_reason)
    VALUES(in_var,'VALUE INELGIBLE');
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unable to Process: Parameter Not Eligible';
WHEN sqlstate 'INVAL' 
THEN
    INSERT INTO LOG_TBL(in_par,error_reason)
    VALUES(in_var,'VALUE INValid');
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unable to Process: Parameter Invalid';
end; 

END;    
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
COST 100;
```

The problem I face is as soon as an exception is raised the records in LOG_TBL in the exception section gets rolled back. Is there an alternative solution where I can insert the record into database table as well as raise an application error?

Comment: why not issue a COMMIT right after the insert and before raising the last exception?

Comment: @RicardoC - ASOAN can't - the custom function runs inside a transaction not outside it.

Comment: @RichardHuxton right... i just learned that Postgres has no nested transactions. ummm SAVEPOINT, maybe? I guess we need to establish from ASOAN if he wants to rollback the actions taken before the call of the function or not, because a COMMIT inside the function may still be the answer... i think.

Comment: @RicardoC - yep, savepoint is a nested transaction and that's what's being used above to catch the exception. That's not what (s)he needs here though - it's an independant/detached transaction that's wanted so the write to log-table can be committed even if the "main" transaction gets rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

In a simple way - you can't. Once you are inside a function, that's it.

You either have to do this in the client layer or loop back in on another connection to log the error. Traditionally you would loop back in via [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), but it might be possible to use [Foreign Data Wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) too - I have to admit I'm not sure.

Edit: Nope, it looks like postgres_fdw [syncs the transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html#AEN172810) between local and remote. Not helpful in this case. Looks like dblink is the obvious choice.